# Rails 3 + Carrierwave + jQuery File Upload fails to upload image file to Openshift server

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, openshift, carrierwave

I am trying to upload image file of size 3.7 MB to Openshift server and get all the time 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error:

*Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at webauto-webauto.rhcloud.com Port 80*

When I upload images of smaller size everything works well.
Please give me some advise how I can solve this problem?

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

after :store, :delete_original_file
include CarrierWave::RMagick
storage :fog

def delete_original_file(new_file)

if self.version_name.nil?
  self.file.delete if self.file.exists?
end
end

def cache_dir
"#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/cache/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def store_dir
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end


def default_url
"#{Rails.root}/public/thumbnail.png"
end


version :original do
process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300], :if=> :dealer_picture?
process :resize_to_limit => [1500, 1500], :if=> :picture?
process :watermark, :if=> :picture?

end

version :medium, :from_version => :original,:if=> :picture? do
process resize_to_limit: [600, 600]
process :watermark
end

version :thumb, :from_version => :medium,:if=> :picture? do
process resize_to_fill: [450, 300]
end



def extension_white_list
%w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end

def watermark
manipulate! do |img|
logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/public/watermark.png").first
img = img.composite(logo, Magick::SouthEastGravity, 25, 25, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
end
end

protected

def picture?(file)
model.class.to_s.underscore=="picture"
end

def dealer_picture?(file)
  model.class.to_s.underscore=="dealer_picture"
end
end
```

Comment: are you on the free tier that OpenShift provides?

Comment: I use Small basic gear, upgrading to Small.highcpu did not help either

Comment: could you show the .htaccess file? I think this may be an issue with max_file_upload_size

Comment: where is this file? first I thought the problem was with file storage in OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, but when I changed to Amazon S3 nothing improved

Comment: can you connect through `ssh` and run `$ quota -s`

Comment: `Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
                   794M       0   1024M           56042       0   80000`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think this is an issue with OpenShift default configuration, I did the following:

```
ssh your_user@your_domain.com
cat /etc/php.ini | grep upload_max
=> 878:upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

So you should try and find out if files below 2M will upload and if bigger files break the app, you should try to contact OpenShift support or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openshift

Comment: Is there any difference what settings are in php.ini file if I work with Ruby on Rails? How can I edit php.ini file?

Comment: @maricavor I think you need sudo permissions, so you should try Openshift support directly

Comment: I cannot contact Openshift directly, I think it is only for silver plan users. It is still strange for me,that I should edit php.ini file for my Rails application on Openshift.

Comment: It breaks the app even if I upload 1.3 MB image file

Comment: Can you run rhc app-tidy and see if that helps?

Comment: Tried before, it did not help